# How does this code generate "()()" when n=2?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
void solve(int n,int open,int close,string s,vector<string>&ans) {
    if(open==close && close==n) {
        ans.push_back(s);
        return;
    }
    if(open<n) {
        s+="(";
        solve(n,open+1,close,s,ans);
        s.pop_back();
    }
    if(open>close) {
        s+=")";
        solve(n,open,close+1,s,ans);
        s.pop_back();
    }
}
vector<string> generateParentheses(int n) {
    vector<string> ans;
    solve(n,0,0,"",ans);
    return ans;
}
```

This piece of code generates all possible permutations of parantheses for a given value n. I can easily dry run the code when n=2 and reach to the output "(())". But I really don't understand how it reaches to "()()".

The point where I get stuck is "()". The code can't close the bracket till the no of opening brackets is equal to n.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and step through it?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: From what I can tell, all you need is `else if` for the `if (open > close)` statement.

Comment: what is "dry run" ? I have read this several times, but till now I didnt get a reply to what it means.

Comment: It reaches _both_ `(())` and `()()`. Isn't that what you designed the code to do?

Comment: *"The code can't close the bracket till the no of opening brackets is equal to n."* -- false, hence your confusion. When things don't make sense, question your assumptions.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number *"what is 'dry run' ?"* -- I believe this means walking through the code by hand.

Comment: Adding some debug output will ease understanding the flow of the program: https://godbolt.org/z/o8v5bz1oT

Answer (score 1):

After `"()"`, `open` is 1, `close` is 1, `n` is 2.

It will enter:

```
if(open<n) {
    s+="(";
    solve(n,open+1,close,s,ans);
    s.pop_back();
}
```

effectively going to `"()("`. You should be able to trace the rest from here.